# java function to convert alphanumeric to integers

Tags: java

I'm trying to achieve the below logic in Java but stuck up as I'm a beginner.

I need to convert `1A`, `1B`, `2A`, `2B`, `3A`, `3B`...etc to `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`...etc.The logic or the function should return the equivalent integer of the alphanumeric that I pass as input.

Note: There will only be two alphabets A and B. The numbers will keep increasing sequentially.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in `java` or `javascript` and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why does `1B` map to `2`?  What should `14A6c` map to?  You need to more clearly define what transformation you're expecting; we could give you any number of incorrect functions that give back the examples you provided.

Comment: Suppose you first convert 1A to 10, and 1B to 11. Does that give you a hint?

Comment: Is the idea that dL (where d is a digit and L is a letter) maps to `2*(d-1)+(L=='B'?1:0)`?

Comment: So `nA` maps to 2n-1, and `nB` maps to 2n?

Comment: The format will always be "DL" where D is a digit and L is a letter. The letters will always be either A or B and nothing else. However, the numbers will keep increasing. For example the result for 1A is 1, 1B is 2, 2A is 3, 2B is 4, 3A is 5 etc.

Comment: I've removed the JavaScript tag. You mention Java three times, so I'm pretty sure that's what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help you if you work out the finer points for yourself, but here's the main points.

1. You can use `String.charAt()` to retrieve the digit and the letter.
2. To convert the digit character into an integer, you can cast it to an `int` and then subtract 48 (because 48 is the ASCII code for `0`).
3. Then you should test whether the letter is `A` or `B`. If it's `A`, then the answer is 2d-1, where d is the digit value. If it's `B`, the answer is 2d.